# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'myFile'

Tags: python, argparse

I am relatively new to python and trying to understand network code written in python. I however encounter this problem when I run the code. The relevant part of the code is as shown below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="write data file for optimization model")
  parser.add_argument("--graph", metavar="myFile", default=" ", type=str, help="graphml file")
  parser.add_argument("--budget", type=int, default=0, help='budget')
  parser.add_argument("--nsamples", type=int, default=0,help='number of random samples')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  
  budget = getattr(args, 'budget')
  graphFile = getattr(args, 'myFile')
  nsamples = getattr(args, 'nsamples')
  roadSegGraph = nx.read_graphml(graphFile)
```

**The error is**

C:\Users\aduam\anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/aduam/Downloads/smartcities-master (2)/smartcities-master/Models/real_soc_function/write_data.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aduam\Downloads\smartcities-master (2)\smartcities-master\Models\real_soc_function\write_data.py", line 344, in 
graphFile = getattr(args, 'myFile')
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'myFile'

Comment: Use `print(args)` to see what is actually in that Namespace..  Did you try `args.graph`?

Comment: You mean args.graph for in place of which part exactly?

Comment: The default `dest` is taken from the long option string `"--graph".

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more? I think I tried the option but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metavar` modifies the name of the argument in the outputted help/usage message **only**, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar):

> Note that metavar only changes the displayed name - the name of the attribute on the `parse_args()` object is still determined by the `dest` value.

You are looking for [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest).

Also, i'm not sure why you are using `getattr`.

```py
budget = getattr(args, 'budget')
graphFile = getattr(args, 'myFile')
nsamples = getattr(args, 'nsamples')
```

can and should just be

```py
budget = args.budget
graphFile = args.myFile
samples = args.nsamples
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried the suggested option but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you actually try to use `dest='myFile'`? If so you should **update** the question with the current code and error

Comment: Oh yeah. It works. Initially forgot to replace the **metavar** with **dest**. Replacing the two fixes the problem. Thank you